# Calling a function when condition is true

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having some trouble with calling the countdown function when the result of the above query is true. Basically the script checks if a user has permission and displays a message if they do, then counts down and redirects them to a new page. I've ran the code through a syntax checker and it comes out valid.

But on inspection of the browser debugger I get the error 'countdown' is undefined. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
function validate() {
    var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "UserName"
    });
    var query = '<Query>' +
        '<Where>' +
        '<Eq>' +
        '<FieldRef Name="userid" />' +
        '<Value Type="User">' + userName + '</Value>' +
        '</Eq>' +
        '</Where>' +
        '</Query>';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices({

            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "test",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='userid' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

                var matchFound = false; //define flag


                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    if (userName == $(this).attr("ows_userid")) {
                        matchFound = true; //set the flag to true indicating matched record
                    }

                    function countdown() {

                        var time_left = 5;
                        var cinterval;
                        var timestatus = 1;
                        var targetURL = "http://www.google.com"

                        function time_dec() {
                            time_left--;
                            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
                            if (time_left == 0) {
                                clearInterval(cinterval);
                                window.location = targetURL
                            }
                        }

                        function defaultstart() {
                            time_left = 5;
                            clearInterval(cinterval);
                            cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
                        }

                        defaultstart();
                    }
                });
                if (matchFound)
                    $('#validmsg').css('visibility', 'visible');

                else
                    $('#denymsg').css('visibility', 'visible');
                if (matchFound) {
                    countdown()
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what line is the error referring to?

Comment: @RScott please format the code next time you are asking some question. It will help users to read it better.

Comment: After formatting your code the answer is obvious. It's out of scope. Always format your code or you will always have this problem.

Comment: seems to be referring to the jquery file? which is odd because the countdown function is one I created myself.

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting, for some reason when I pasted it in some lines where outside the code box

Comment: It's not referring to any one, because it's not defined in the scope you're using it. My advice is start over and format your code as you go. If you keep your house messy you will get bugs. If your code is messy, you will get bugs.

Comment: Looks like HTML element name and function name are same. Try to change either one of these to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

It's out of scope. You should define `countdown()` outside the loop if you want to call it from outside. Besides I don't see the need to put it inside, you don't seem to be using any of the xData.

```
var matchFound = false;
function countdown() {
    var time_left = 5;
    var cinterval;
    var timestatus = 1;
    var targetURL = "http://www.google.com"

    function time_dec() {
        time_left--;
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
        if (time_left == 0) {
            clearInterval(cinterval);
            window.location = targetURL
        }
    }

    function defaultstart() {
        time_left = 5;
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
    }

    defaultstart();
}
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    if (userName == $(this).attr("ows_userid")) {
        matchFound = true; //set the flag to true indicating matched record
    }
});
if (matchFound) {
    $('#validmsg').css('visibility', 'visible');
    countdown();
} else {
    $('#denymsg').css('visibility', 'visible');     
}
```